# Using find with vector<pair<int, int>>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, find

I ran into the following problem: suppose I have

```
pair<int, int> p(1,2)
vector<pair<int, int>> vec;
```

I want to use find to get the iterator pointing to the element p in the vector

```
find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), p)
```

But it gave me the error

```
type 'std::__1::pair<int, int>' does not provide a call operator
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon.

Comment: [Works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3310f63bca8b7a63) for me. Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Could you provide the full example?

Answer (score -1):

This is what I've used and it's worked great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct FindPair {
    FindPair (int first, int second)
    : m_first_value(first)
    , m_second_value(second) { }

    int m_first_value;
    int m_second_value;
    bool operator()
        ( const std::pair<int, int> &p ) {
            return (p.first == m_first_value && p.second == m_second_value);
    }
};


int main()
{

    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> > myVec;
    std::vector< std::pair<int, int> >::iterator it;

    myVec.push_back(std::make_pair(1,1));
    myVec.push_back(std::make_pair(1,2));

    it = std::find_if(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), FindPair(1, 2));

    if (it != myVec.end())
    {
        // We Found it
        std::cout << "Matched Found on Current Iterator!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "it.first: " << (*it).first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "it.second: " << (*it).second << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Nothing Matched!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Matched Found on Current Iterator! 
it.first: 1 
it.second: 2
```

Comment: The OP doesn't say anywhere that he wants to compare using the first element in the `pair`. Since he wants to compare both elements, `find` works because `operator==` is defined for `pair`.

Comment: Your correct, I've updated my answer to be more complete.

Comment: Why are you still using `find_if` and `FindPair`? Here's a much simpler version of your example - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2be33cdeef2db054

Comment: find_if and FindPair are powerful and expandable as needed.  You can modify it to search by the specific key, value or both as needed.  It's also easy to follow and tells you exactly what it's doing. It can be re-used later on in many different situations.